# Not getting the first character of the string and get the data which is in a parenthesis using regex

Tags: python, regex, web, web-scraping

Main string : 'Netflix|Prime Video|Disney+Hotstar|YoutubeOperating System: AndroidUltra HD (4K) 3840 x 2160 Pixels30 W Speaker Output60 Hz Refresh Rate3 x HDMI | 2 x USBA+ Grade1 Year'

1. code of regex (OTT): `re.findall( r'^\w(.*?)O|U$', Tv_df['Features'][1])`
   o/p : ['etflix|Prime Video|Disney+Hotstar|Youtube']
2. code of regex (Type): `re.findall(r'[a-z]+\s(?:HD|SD)', Tv_df['Features'][1])`
   o/p : ['ltra HD', 'x HD']

- The output for OTT regex is correct but the first charcter 'N' is missing.
- The output for type regex should be `Ultra HD (4K)` . I'm facing the same problem that is the first character 'U' is missing and the data '4K' should be extracted which is in the paranthesis.

P.S : Please find the main string above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Move the `\w` inside the `(` like: `^(\w.*?)O|U$` to match the first letter.
2. You are not matching the 'U' of ultra, you can do that by adding [A-Z] at the beginning, and you have to match the things inside `( & )` to get `4K`. You can do that by adding `\s\(.+?\)` to the end. So the pattern will look like this: `[A-Z][a-z]+\s(?:HD|SD)`

Comment: Hey! @anotherGatsby your code worked. Thank you very much. Can explain me why dsnt   [a-zA-Z] work in place of [A-Z][a-z] ?

Comment: @LaxmiAgarwal `[a-zA-Z]` means match one character that is either in lower or upper case. `[A-Z][a-z]` means, first match a upper case character then match a lower case character. You used only `[a-z]` which matched 'ltra` but not 'U' of 'Ultra'.